# Can a Codable protocol be used for decoding without exposing the underlying type?

Tags: ios, swift, codable

I want to do something like this where the underlying concrete types are not used, and instead only a `Codable` protocol is used.

```
protocol MyProtocol: Codable {}

struct MyProtocolImpl: MyProtocol {}

struct Something: Codable {
    let x: MyProtocol
}
```

This does not compile with:

> Type 'Something' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

I assume this is intentional by Swift, but I want to check whether I am missing something.

Comment: This is conceivable (though not currently allowed) for Encodable. How do you imagine it working for Decodable? Write down some JSON and determine which of the infinite number of possible types it decodes to.

Comment: I guess I was expecting the OS to call the instance that conforms to `MyProtocol`'s implementation of `init(from decoder: Decoder)`

Comment: What do you mean by "the" instance? There could be infinitely many types that conform to MyProtocol. Which one should it choose? It's legal to conform to protocols in other modules, so the compiler doesn't even know that it can see all possible implementations. Note that MyProtocol has no requirements other than Codable. So there is nothing you can do with `something.x` other than re-encode it, even if this worked.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean now. You’re right - the decoding does not make sense in this case